# Use Regex in Vue Router Paths

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am creating a VueJS app which heavily uses the vue router.

Here's the structure of my `routes.js`:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: Poetry, children: [
        { path: '', name: 'poetry', component: PoetryLanding },
        { path: 'poetry/:id', name: 'poetrycard', component: PoetryCard },
        { path: 'poetry/search', name: 'poetrysearch', component: PoetrySearch },
    ]},
]
```

I want to use regex in second child component i.e. `poetrycard` such that it only accepts the params(`:id`) which is a number. I am doing this because `poetrysearch` gets affected as `/search` is treated as `:id`!

I tried:

```
{ path: 'poetry/:id/[0-9]/g', name: 'poetrycard', component: PoetryCard }
```

But this doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> vue-router uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) as its path matching engine, so it supports many advanced matching patterns such as optional dynamic segments, zero or more / one or more requirements, and even custom regex patterns.

So change your route definition as follows:

```
{ path: 'poetry/:id(\\d+)', name: 'poetrycard', component: PoetryCard }
```

Reference- [Advanced Matching patterns](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work! The page doesn't load at all.

Comment: @Sanjay can you try replacing the regex with `\\d+`

Comment: If anyone is wondering - this also applies to Vue Router aliases eg. `{path: '/abc/:type?', alias: '/something-different/:type?'}`