# Missing required prop in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm getting a "missing required props" error that I can see in the chrome dev tools. I have been following instructions and similar cases, but still against prognostic the props won't move, so I'm starting to think is a conceptual problem.

I have a component like this

```
<template>
  <div class="external">
    <div @click="sendMyProps" class="internal">
 ...
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

being the sendMyProps method within script tag and export default like:

```
  methods: {
    sendMyProps () {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'destiny', params: { menu: 'destiny' }})
    },
```

The main component (it could be irrelevant) storing it among others is :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <External></External>
    <AnotherOne></AnotherOne>
    <AnotherTwo></AnotherTwo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import External from '@/components/External'
import AnotherOne from '@/components/AnotherOne'
import AnotherTwo from '@/components/AnotherTwo'


export default {
  name: 'Main',
  components: {
    External ,
    AnotherOne,
    AnotherTwo,
  }
}
</script>
```

In my routes I have, with all imported:

```
{
  path: '/destiny',
  name: 'destiny',
  components: {
    default: Destiny,
    header: Header,
    footer: Footer
  },
  props: true
}
```

And finally the destination component looks like (it is very big):

```
<template>

  <div class="finalComponent">
      <span @click="active = 'destiny'" :class="{ active: active ==='destiny' }">destiny</span>
      <span @click="active = 'blabla'" :class="{ active: active ==='blabla' }">ASpan</span>
...
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
...

export default {
  created () {
    this.aMethod()

  },
  mounted () {
    this.active = this.$props.menu
  },
...
  props: {
    menu: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'house'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I believe I have everything, yet the variable I need doesn't get loaded. According to chrome dev tools, it is not even sent to the component from the router. A charming soul around that can free me from this distress? Thanks

Comment: In your routes, you are missing prop in the url. `path: '/destiny',` should be `path: '/destiny/:menu?',`, where menu is optional parameter. Optional parameters have `?` at the end

Comment: Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51302701/3226121) if you want to match route param by regex

Comment: That could be. I'm not sure if props obliges to pass the parameters in the URL or if they remain hidden as if they were simply vars passed among forms and divs. It looks like it is the first. But how comes I have never seen something like that yet in old SO questions? Never saw the use of colons until now

Comment: Maybe you just didn't pay attention to the `:`. But that's how `vue-router` works. It passes parameter with `:` as a prop. So if your router component accepts `menu` prop, you can pass it from the route url by using `:menu`. If it's optional param, you can use `?` at the end. It's in **vue-router** docs [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes). You also have [advanced pattern matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route).

Comment: I find this example file from github repository [vue-router/examples/route-matching/app.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js#L13) really useful

Comment: It is of no use. Still the [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "menu"

Somehow it won't push the props

    sendMyProps() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'destiny', params: { menu: 'destiny' }})
    } 
Any idea to test this?

Comment: The props appear in the URL, so now props are being passed, but DEstiny component won´t read it. I can give it a default value, but when I set it to be required  I get the error. At this point, the Destiny component won´t read the props.

Comment: The colon was added BTW. I haven't skipped that

Comment: Because you have multiple components defined in same route, you need to define props differently: change `props: true` to `props: { default: true, header: true, footer: true, }` (change to `false` if you are not passing the prop to component). From the vue-router documentation on [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components): _for routes with named views, you have to define the `props` option for each named view_

Comment: That is interesting. I'm starting to think the problem is the direct call to router passing paths. Probbaly using a router-link tag would solve this situation, but AFAIK both are correct. LEt me try

Comment: My dear @ljubadr you made my day. That was the issue. Sort of an edge case, and that was the solution. Its required to have a props element per component. You made my day :)