# Make Vue.js router to match only numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How do I make it so vue.js's router will only match numbers? For example, if I set a a route

```
{
    path: "/:id",
    name: "RouteName",
    component: SomeComponent,
    props: true
}
```

How do I make it so it will only match urls like localhost:8080/983 and localhost:8080/239 and not match urls like localhost:8080/nan and localhost:8080/string?

Edit: I have tried to use regexes and it didn't work so I want something other than regexes.

Comment: You can use some sort of regex for your routes. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302405/use-regex-in-vue-router-paths)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Use Regex in Vue Router Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302405/use-regex-in-vue-router-paths)

Comment: @NinoFiliu I have tried using regexes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
{
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: "RouteName",
      component: SomeComponent,
      props: (route) => {
        const id= Number.parseInt(route.params.id, 10)
        if (Number.isNaN(id)) {
          return 0
        }
        return { id }
      }
    }
```