# Use regex in Vue Router path to exclude a specific directory

Tags: node.js, regex, vue.js, vue-router, vite

I would like to exclude the public assets directory. I'm also excluding server side, but somehow it still gets redirected if the URL is clicked from my webapp. (Not from a hard reload or from Firefox, this only happens in Chromium based browsers somehow)

I have the following to redirect everything to a 404 page:
`{path: '/:pathMatch(.*)', component: NotFound}`

I tried the following regex: `(?!^\/?assets\/?.*$)(^.*$)` on see: https://regex101.com/r/jc3u9e/1

I tried the following:

```
const routes = [
    {path: '/index.html', redirect: '/'},
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/portfolio', component: Portfolio},
    {path: '/cv', component: Resume},
    {path: '/contact', component: Contact},
    {path: '(?!^\\/?assets\\/?.*$)(^.*$)', component: NotFound}
]
```

This also doesn't work: `{path: '/:pathMatch((?!^\\/?assets\\/?.*$)(^.*$))', component: NotFound}`

I have read the following:

- [Use Regex in Vue Router Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302405/use-regex-in-vue-router-paths)
- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route
- https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp
- https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex

Unfortunately I have no clue how to achieve this.

## Portfolio open source

See GitHub repo of my code: https://github.com/Remzi1993/remzi-info I use Node.js with Vite with Vue.js and TypeScript template.
The server config is a file configuration called: netlify.toml

```
# Redirects
[[redirects]]
from = "/assets/cv.pdf"
to = "/cv"
status = 301

[[redirects]]
from = "/cv.html"
to = "/cv"
status = 301

[[redirects]]
from = "/contact.html"
to = "/contact"
status = 301

[[redirects]]
from = "/index.php"
to = "/"
status = 301

# Default favicon redirect
[[redirects]]
from = "/favicon.ico"
to = "/assets/img/logo.png"
status = 301

# Pages
[[redirects]]
from = "/"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200

[[redirects]]
from = "/portfolio"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200

[[redirects]]
from = "/cv"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200

[[redirects]]
from = "/contact"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200

# Public assets directory
[[redirects]]
from = "/assets/*"
to = "/assets/:splat"
status = 200
force = true

# 404
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 404

# Netlify build proceeds only if there are changes within the src directory
[build]
ignore = "git diff --quiet $COMMIT_REF $CACHED_COMMIT_REF -- src/"
```

Comment: Vue router handles urls that are changed during navigation, e.g. with router.push . You aren't supposed to navigate asset urls. They aren't handled by the router. This is likely XY problem. If you have problems with the assets in your app, consider reasking the question with the details. " somehow it still gets redirected if the URL is clicked from my webapp" - clicked how?

Comment: You can block access to a folder, but that will mean your app will not be allowed to load resources from that folder. That's probably not what you want. And, if it is, why don't you just delete the folder?

Comment: @EstusFlask with a normal HTML a tag not a router-link, it shouldn't happen, but the strange thing is that it only happens in Chromium based browsers. On Firefox if you click the link it will load a .pdf file or open a new I age in a tab.

Comment: @tao That's not what I want or need. I want a public assets directory where I can put .pdf files or other things others can link to and open without Vue interfering. I want to exclude Vue and Vue Router from the directory

Comment: It's XY problem, as I said, you're addressing the wrong cause. You never need what you're trying to do with Vue router. Could be wrong server config but then it would affect all browsers. Can't say what happens without seeing it.

Comment: @EstusFlask Okay, it's about my personal portfolio which is also open source, I will update it with my GitHub link

Comment: I personally think it's a weird caching problem with Chromium based browsers, because other browsers go directly reach for example: https://remzi.info/assets/Curriculum-vitae-R.Cavdar.pdf and this also goes directly to a logo on Firefox: https://remzi.info/assets/img/logo.png but not in Chromium browsers. It's really strange.

Comment: I see what you mean. Clicking on it initiates a download, and opening it in another window results in 404 page (although it's served with 200 code). It's easier to debug for .png because devtools are available for both cases. It can be seen that when opened in a new tab the difference is `Status Code: 200  (from service worker)`, i.e. index.html is served by SW. I don't deal with Netlify and can't say why this happen, but the obvious difference is that they are requested with different headers, and the response is sensitive to them. Didn't check in FF but it doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: The problem is Netlify server config and/or its SW. Doesn't have to do anything with Vue router. This wouldn't happen if index.html weren't served instead of static file

Comment: @EstusFlask I fixed the issue by dumping my important public assets to a subdomain. I created an assets.remzi.info subdomain and put all my files there.